# OpenShift Requirements.txt Pip error

Tags: python, pip, openshift

I want to deploy a Python app to OpenShift and the app is using the tweepy library in it. For tweepy, easy_install not working, so I created a requirements.txt file which has only one line "tweepy", but I'm getting an error parse_requirements() got an unexpected keyword argument 'session' and permission denied. Really don't know what it is. I searched a lot, but none of the solutions are worked. As a solution, I tried to install it manually, but I cannot reach the sudo level and it does not allow me to use pip. Thanks in advance.

```
    Checking for pip dependency listed in requirements.txt file..                                     
    remote: Downloading/unpacking tweepy (from -r /var/lib/openshift/556db0635004460bb70000f6/app-root/runtime
    /repo/requirements.txt (line 1))                                                                          
    remote:   Downloading tweepy-3.3.0.tar.gz                                                                 
    remote:   Running setup.py egg_info for package tweepy                                                    
    remote:     Traceback (most recent call last):                                                            
    remote:       File "<string>", line 16, in <module>                                                       
    remote:       File "/var/lib/openshift/556db0635004460bb70000f6/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virte
    nv/build/tweepy/setup.py", line 17, in <module>                                                           
    remote:         install_reqs = parse_requirements('requirements.txt', session=uuid.uuid1())               
    remote:     TypeError: parse_requirements() got an unexpected keyword argument 'session'                  
    remote:     Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:                                        
    remote:     Traceback (most recent call last):                                                            
    remote: 
    remote:   File "<string>", line 16, in <module>                                                           
    remote: 
    remote:   File "/var/lib/openshift/556db0635004460bb70000f6/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/b
    uild/tweepy/setup.py", line 17, in <module>                                                               
    remote: 
    remote:     install_reqs = parse_requirements('requirements.txt', session=uuid.uuid1())                   
    remote: 
    remote: TypeError: parse_requirements() got an unexpected keyword argument 'session' 
remote: ----------------------------------------                                                          
remote: Cleaning up...                                                                                    
remote: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /var/lib/openshift/556db0635004460bb7
0000f6/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/build/tweepy                                          
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                
remote:   File "/var/lib/openshift/556db0635004460bb70000f6/python/virtenv/bin/pip", line 12, in <module> 
remote:     load_entry_point('pip==1.4.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()                                    
remote:   File "/var/lib/openshift/556db0635004460bb70000f6/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/l
ib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 148, in main                                            
remote:     return command.main(args[1:], options)                                                        
remote:   File "/var/lib/openshift/556db0635004460bb70000f6/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/l
ib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 171, in main                                         
remote:     log_fp = open_logfile(log_fn, 'w')                                                            
remote:   File "/var/lib/openshift/556db0635004460bb70000f6/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/l
ib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 200, in open_logfile                                 
remote:     os.makedirs(dirname)                                                                          
remote:   File "/var/lib/openshift/556db0635004460bb70000f6/python/virtenv/lib64/python2.6/os.py", line 15
7, in makedirs                                                                                            
remote:     mkdir(name, mode)                                                                             
remote: OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/openshift/556db0635004460bb70000f6/.pip'
```

Comment: Which cartridge are you using?

Comment: I'm using the bottle cartridge which is maintained in Github: 
https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/bottle-openshift-quickstart

Comment: Did you managed to solve this?

Comment: @AlexanderFradiani unfortunately no.

Comment: I was able to run pip install <package> from ssh session in the app, is the only workaround I know now.